# access to result of mocked method with autospec

Tags: django, unit-testing, mocking

Have in *integration* test:

```
with mock.patch.object(
   EmailMultiAlternatives, 'send', autospec=True,
   side_effect=EmailMultiAlternatives.send
) as mocked_mail_send:
   method_using_that_send()
   mocked_mail_send             # how to access here send's return value ?
```

Mocking purpose is to verify if my method will call external method, but I don't want mock entirely that send method and overwrite original return_value.

Answer (score 0):

Found it as impossible to achieve in mock.

Resolved by splitting test to:

- unit test with mocked `send`
- integration test testing only result from that external `send`.